# ios Change background of static TableView

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, background, uitableview

I'm trying to put a background image into a UITableViewController with static cells inside.

Usually, in normal UIViewControllers I do this by changing the UIViewController's background color and setting the tableview's background color to clearcolor and opaque to NO

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultBackground.png"]];
self.tableView.opaque = NO;
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

but doing this in my UITableViewController with static cell's leaves me with a transparent tableview with a black background. It seems like there is no view underneath.
I tried to add the view and make it contain the tableview, but this leaded to an empty view without the tableview.

```
self.view = [UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.tableview.frame;
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.tableView];

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultBackground.png"]];

self.tableView.opaque = NO;
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I've found a little work around, changing the tableview background color directly  `self.tableview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultBackground.png"]];`
Although this is not what I want... the image seems to repeat while the tableview scrolls.

Comment: you should set `tableview.backgroundView`

Comment: Yes, this worked good. Thank you! If you post it I'll be glad to signal it as the correct answer 

`self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];
    
self.tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:background];
    
[self.tableView sendSubviewToBack:self.tableView.backgroundView];
    
self.tableView.opaque = NO;
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`